# How to fix the parse tree error about ANTLR in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have installed the ANTLR tool plugin for Eclipse and it auto-generates the Java classes correctly but it failed to build a parse tree, and the progress bar about building a parse tree is always going. There are some errors in the console.

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/BaseErrorListener
>       at com.github.jknack.antlr4ide.runtime.Antlr4Server.run(Antlr4Server.java:66)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.BaseErrorListener
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 1 more

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue is solved by following the below steps in Eclipse.

```
Windows -> Preference

ANTLR4 -> Tool 

ANTLR Tool - Add the correct version of ANTLR JAR.
Also, click on "Configure Project Specific Settings" to check if an incorrect path is set.
```

[image]